# Laravel: Pulled my laravel project from Bitbucket in Windows but It won't work

Tags: laravel-4, permissions

I have been maintaining my Laravel Project in Ubuntu and BitBucket previously. The application runs fine on Ubuntu. However, recently I tried to pull my application from BitBucket into Windows7 and I get the following errors:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

I have Composer Installed on Windows7 and I tried `composer` command in command line which works fine.

Anyone can help?

**Updated**

- Tried `composer update` and I get the version errors ([image: attached]), looks like I don't have compatible version of PHP. I have `v5.3.8`

Comment: Try running `composer update`

Comment: Thanks @lukasgeiter. See my updates. Looks like I don't have compatible php version.

Comment: Yes you need at least PHP 5.4. If you don't know how to update, [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/106271) might help.